# Using data attribute to pull in JS content

Tags: javascript

So I'm not too familiar with data attributes and I wanted to see if I get can get some help from others.

I have an HTML portion as shown below:

`<div class="columns is-multiline app-list"></div>`

The `app-list` is being rendered by the following JS:

Is there a way that instead of calling `app-list` as a class, that I can do something like this:

`<div class="columns is-multiline" data-source="application_launcher"></div>`?

All help would be appreciated!

Comment: Yes. `document.querySelector("[data-source=application_launcher]")` or whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the data-attribute as an `selector` in the `querySelector(selector)` method.

In your case just replace

```
const apps_target = document.querySelector('.app-list');
```

with the following line.

```
const apps_target = document.querySelector('[data-source="application_launcher"]');
```